# How do I prevent a thief from reading my SD card?

Tags: security, sd-card, lost-phone

If my device is lost or stolen, how can I prevent others from reading the contents of the data on the SD card?

Comment: Depending on the handset, if there's Device Manager used as the administrator's tool and is installed, visiting [Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and click on 'Erase' would do it no?

Comment: Weapons of mass destruction might help. Check the [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-button-controllertrial/com.kober.headset), some of those apps provide a remote-wipe, which might include wiping the sdcard. On some devices, device encryption can include your sdcard. But you might need to weight that against the trouble you're causing yourself: if your device dies, there's no way you yourself could read the data anymore. So parallel, you should take care to have a good off-device backup.

Comment: Mass destruction - lol! +1 :D

Comment: @t0mm13b As long as that stupid thing is working. I cannot even get it locating or ringing my device, not to speak of its other features... And yeah, "mass (storage device) destruction" ;)

Comment: @Izzy true that, and yes it does feel clunky and sometimes fail for me... *le sigh* Even Cerberus might be more comforting than that...

Comment: No doubt. I tried it with 3 or 4 devices, ranging from Android 2.3.6 to 4.1.1, no luck.